# Problems with Webhooks and Websockets on the same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, backend, webhooks

I have a server that receives webhooks, sends them to a client via websockets. Since I am listening for both on the same port, if webhooks work, websockets dont and vice versa. How would I go about solving this. Here is the code for the server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200);
    res.send(req.body);
    echo(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log('Server is live at 3000'));

const WebSocket = require('ws');
const SocketServer = require('ws').Server;

const server = express().listen(3000);

const wss = new SocketServer({server});

wss.on('connection', (ws) =>{
    console.log("Connected");
    ws.send("Connected To Server")
    ws.on('close', () => console.log("Disconnected"));
});

function echo(webhook){
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client){
        client.send(webhook);
    });
}
```

1. How would I run webhook listener and websocket sender/listener on same port
2. Can I run both of them on different ports on the same url

   a) If yes what would be the url for both ports, if my website is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
3. If all that is not possible, what would be a good alternative